# Could someone explain to me the process described in this quote from G.B. Shaw (fragile load transfer system of some sort)?

Tags: rail

The idea, as I understand it, is to transfer fragile material (glass bulbs in this case, I believe) from one moving *something* to another, or over to a platform. This is taking place in the 1920's, I think. Anyway, here's the quote:

> However, I suffered myself to be taken to Battersea; and there, sure
>   enough, I found a workshop, duly labelled as the premises of The New
>   Transport Company, Limited, and spacious enough to accommodate a
>   double railway line with a platform.  The affair was unquestionably
>   real, so far.
>
> The platform was not provided with a station: its sole equipment was a
>   table with a row of buttons on it for making electrical contacts. Each
>   line of railway had on it a truck with a steel lid. The practical part
>   of the proceedings began by placing an armchair on the lid of one of
>   the trucks and seating me in it.  A brimming glass of water was then
>   set at my feet.  I could not imagine what I was expected to do with
>   the water or what was going to happen; and there was a suggestion of
>   electrocution about the chair which made me nervous.
>
> Gattie then sat down majestically at the table on the platform with
>   his hand hovering over the buttons.  Intimating that the miracle would
>   take place when my truck passed the other truck, he asked me to choose
>   whether it should occur at the first passage or later, and to dictate
>   the order in which it should be repeated.
>
> I was by that time incapable of choosing; so I said the sooner the
>   better; and the two trucks started.  When the other truck had passed
>   mine I found myself magically sitting on it, chair and all, with the
>   glass of water unspilled at my feet.

1. Does "a double railway line" mean two tracks running parallel to each other? Are they linked? Is a switch involved?
2. Are the trucks - trucks (i.e. bogies) that look like this:

[image]

or are they flatbed freight cars that look like this:

[image]

3. **Most important**: how was the author (G.B. Shaw) transferred (along with the glass of water) over to the other - moving - whatever it was?

Comment: 1. Yes, this means that you have two parallel tracks. This is useful if you want to circulate trains in both directions. In case of a line with a single track, trains would typically have to wait in stations if another train uses the track in the opposite direction. Double railway lines are usually linked with several switches. They allow to bypass any sections where accidents happened or maintenance is being done.

Comment: Interesting stuff: can you give us the source info (book, journal, whatever)?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a real description or a sci-fi book?

Comment: @MWijnand: Right ... What about the other two?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Sure. It's the preface to the play titled "The Apple Cart" by G.B. Shaw. Here: http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300431h.html

Comment: @hazzey: It's a real actual description. From the 1920's.

Comment: @Ricky Yes it's a "real" description, but it has nothing to do with engineering. It's a Socialist rant against the evils of Capitalism. Start from "So much for my broadcast on Democracy! And now a word about Breakages, Limited" two paragraphs earlier, and read to the end of the preface. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bernard_Shaw#Political_awakening:_Marxism.2C_socialism.2C_Fabian_Society

Comment: @alephzero: Yes, I understand it's part of the rant. What I'm interested in, though, is how was it done? A platform is transferred from one bogie to another so smoothly that the water glass sitting on it isn't even shaken: how?

Comment: Without an actual description of the device that did the transferring this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: 2nd paragraph "... truck with a steel lid...". It is difficult to see how a lid would be placed on a bogey (British English). In older mines, underground rail trucks, hauled by a locomotive, were used to transport ore & waste to the tipping point, near the hoisting shaft, on each level. These were 4 sided wagons with a open top. I have also read & heard how, in WW 2, Jews were transported to death camps in rail cattle trucks. Some people would have called them cattle cars or wagons. It would fair to assume a truck in this case would be a wagon "with a steel lid" on it.